# Parallax effect fails across multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, haml, parallax

I am trying to make a parallax effect and I am using jQuery for this.
Here is my code:

```
function scrollEffectTop() {
 $('[class^=scrollEffect-top-]').each(function() {
  if ($('[class^=scrollEffect-top-]').length) {
   var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
   var classID_top = $('[class^=scrollEffect-top-]').attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
   $('.scrollEffect-top-' + classID_top).css({'transform':'translateY(-' + scrolled * (classID_top / 100) + 'px)'});
  }
 });
}

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
 scrollEffectTop();
});
```

Basically, I want to match the class name `scrollEffect-top-` and then look for a number after. For example: `scrollEffect-top-15`, means `transform: translateY(- scrolled * (15 / 100)px)`, or `transform: translateY (- scrolled * .15)px`.

The code works well for the first class name in HTML but if I use multiple items with the same class name but **different** number (`classID_top` number) it doesn't work.

Note: that if I use the same number, the code works well.

I tried to search and I found `.each()` method but it still doesn't work.

I am using HAML, here is my code:

```
%section{class:"container-m relative"}
 .intro-image{style:"overflow: hidden;"}
  .scrollEffect-top-15
   .revealedBox.goRight
    %div{class:"picture-for-#{controller.action_name} contentBox"}
```

Here is an actual HTML code:

```
<section class="container-m relative">
 <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="scrollEffect-top-15">
   <div class="revealBox goRight">
    <div class="picture-for-#{controller.action_name} contentBox"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML, and how/where `scrollEffectTop()` is called?

Comment: @PaulRoub I am using `HAML`. Edited. Please, let me know if you need an actual `HTML` code.

Comment: Actual HTML would be better, otherwise anyone wanting to test this would need to do the conversion themselves. And we still don't see *where* `scrollEffectTop()` is called. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulRoub Edited. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.each()` is a good start. Within the `each` function, `this` will refer to the specific item we're looking at. Any modifications can be made through *that*, rather than via the class (which will affect *all* matching objects).

```js
function scrollEffectTop() {
  $('[class^=scrollEffect-top-]').each(function() {
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var classID_top = $(this).attr('class').match(/\d+/)[0];
    $(this).css('transform',
      'translateY(-' + scrolled * (classID_top / 100) + 'px)');
  });
}

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  scrollEffectTop();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container-m relative">
  <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="scrollEffect-top-20">
      <div class="revealedBox goRight">
        <div class="picture-for-foo contentBox">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="container-m relative">
  <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="scrollEffect-top-21">
      <div class="revealedBox goRight">
        <div class="picture-for-foo contentBox">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="container-m relative">
  <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="scrollEffect-top-22">
      <div class="revealedBox goRight">
        <div class="picture-for-foo contentBox">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="container-m relative">
  <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="scrollEffect-top-23">
      <div class="revealedBox goRight">
        <div class="picture-for-foo contentBox">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="container-m relative">
  <div class="intro-image" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="scrollEffect-top-24">
      <div class="revealedBox goRight">
        <div class="picture-for-foo contentBox">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Works!! Finally! Thank you very much!